# TypeORM query builder find where id equals PostgreSQL UUID

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, uuid, typeorm, query-builder

I have a table with `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')`.
When I try to query it with TypeORM query builder, I get error

```
QueryFailedError: invalid input syntax for type uuid: "{"id":"8f294654-8385-4579-a714-0fae73839430"}"
```

The query is

```
this.repository.createQueryBuilder('products')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('products.brand', 'brands')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('products.category', 'categories')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('products.productOptions', 'productOptions')
  .where('products.id = :id', { id })
  .getOne()
```

Is there a way to cast string uuid to postgresql uuid?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `id` is expecting `"8f294654-8385-4579-a714-0fae73839430"` but somehow you passed an object of `{"id":"8f294654-8385-4579-a714-0fae73839430"}`.